# Регулярные выражения C# Выборка текста

Tags: c#

Не могу составить правильно регулярное выражение. Помогите!

Есть вот такой текст

```
Supplier 
Aker Solutions Malaysia, 
PKFZ Malaysia  
QS Plan ID/Project 
ITP Number
```

Написан именно в таком порядке с переходами по строкам.

Нужно вытянуть `Supplier` любой текст `QS Plan ID/Project (\n) ITP Number` Вытянуть все но текст после Suppler может быть любой до QS. Уже сломал голову.

Comment: Картинку текстом замени.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/PPoTcG

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = 
@"Supplier
Aker Solutions Malaysia,
PKFZ Malaysia
QS Plan ID/Project
ITP Number";

        var match = Regex.Match(text, "Supplier\n(?:.*\n){2}(.*)\n(.*)");
        var res1 = match.Groups[1];
        var res2 = match.Groups[2];

        Console.WriteLine(res1);
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/4fAvXP

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = 
@"Supplier
Aker Solutions Malaysia,
PKFZ Malaysia
Aker Solutions Malaysia,
PKFZ Malaysia
QS Plan ID/Project
ITP Number";

        var match = Regex.Match(text, "Supplier\n(?:(?!QS).*\n)*(.*)\n(.*)");
        var res1 = match.Groups[1];
        var res2 = match.Groups[2];

        Console.WriteLine(res1);
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает. И текст "Aker Solutions Malaysia,
PKFZ Malaysia" может быть любой.

Comment: @АртурОлеговичПлюх, обновил для любого числа строк.

Comment: @АртурОлеговичПлюх, если не работает, сделай fork на ideone и вставь пример, на котором не работает.

Comment: http://vfl.ru/fotos/e35a6b3716344897.html  Пусто не находит. http://zalivalka.ru/359138 Вот фаил текстовый вот в таком файле надо это найти.

Comment: Я вот тут проверяю регулярки http://regexstorm.net/tester